# Formal Writing "Persuade" vs. "Convince"

Tags: verbs, formality, academia

A colleague of mine is a second language speaker of English. He is seeking work in academia after he graduates with a cover letter. Would it be more appropriate to use "Persuade" or "Convince" a potential employer that he has the skills required for their position?

Which of the following examples would be more professional in a cover letter for a job application:

> I hope that my CV can *convince* you that I have the suitable experience for the position.
>
> I hope that my CV can *persuade* you that I have the suitable experience for the position.

Comment: Purely a personal opinion, but I think you tend to *persuade* someone to believe a falsehood or do something wrong, but *convince* them to accept a truth or do the right thing.

Comment: My recommendation was also against "persuade" to avoid it's connotation with seduction. I am curious whether anyone has a better or _more convincing_ reason or context for one over another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "persuade" and "convince"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38438/whats-the-difference-between-persuade-and-convince)

Answer (score 1):

Both words mean to bring someone around to support an argument advanced, in this case that particular someone is potential employer and the argument is that your friend is qualified. Sticklers claim that you must *persuade* a person to act and convince a person only to believe.  Of the distinction, Steven Pinker says in *A Sense of Style*

> "...few writers care."

And a brief dance with the google convinced me that he's right and persuaded me to write this answer.

Comment: Your final sentence conforms to the *syntactic* distinction made by Bill Bryson and summarized in [this Guardian piece:](http://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2011/feb/11/mind-your-language-convince-persuade) *[Bryson] declares it is **possible to persuade** someone to do something **without convincing** them of the correctness or necessity of doing it. He also alerts us to a grammatical difference: **persuade** may be followed by an infinitive, but **convince** may not.* But presumably you don't agree with Bryson's *first* point as made there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, my last sentence so conforms, and I'd mark these  things if it didn't require learning how to use emoticons.  My first sentence may lead readers to believe that *persuade* only means to induce belief, and that's not true.  You may persuade someone to belief or action, so Bryson's first point is valid.  But writers follow *convince* with infinitives all the time, caring little, as PInker notes, about these dicta.

Comment: [Apparently,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will+convince+you+to%2Cwill+persuade+you+to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20convince%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20persuade%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0) *convince + infinitive* wasn't very popular until a few decades ago, but it's actually more common than ***persuade** + infinitive* now. Rules are made to be broken, as they say.